# Find the probability distribution of X?

Tags: probability, self-study, binomial-distribution

Suppose Nokia store places 20 of its cell phones on a clearance sale, unknown to anyone 5 of these cell phones are defective. A customer selects 3 cell phones at random for inspection. Let X be the number of defective cell phones in the sample. Find the probability distribution of X?

My attempt:

$$
        \begin{matrix}
        x & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
        P(X=x) & 0.015625 & 0.140625 & 0.421875 & 0.421875 \\
        \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

I calculated the values using the binomial distribution: $$
P(X = x) = nCx \ p^{n-x} (1-p)^x$$

Where, $n$=5, $x$=0,1,2,3 and $p$=(.25) [from 5/20]

Comment: You think correctly but your formula is wrong...
$$\textrm{P}(X=x) = C_n^x p^x (1-p)^{n-x},$$ with
$$C_n^x = \frac{n!}{x! (n - x)!},$$
$n$ the number of trials, and $p$ the probability of success (here, drawing a defective cell phone)

Comment: @ocram It's definitely *not* binomial. The phones are sampled *without replacement*, so the trials are not independent.

Comment: @Glen_b: You are right!

Comment: Please, don't [cross-post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). I'm closing without migrating because Henry gave the same answer on math.se.

Answer (score 2):

Also asked at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/244154/find-the-probability-distribution-of-x where I said:

No it is not correct.

In particular with only a quarter of the phones defective, getting three defectives out of three in the sample should have a low probability.

A second point is that the customer is presumably looking at three different phones (sampling *without replacement*), so you should not be using the binomial distribution but instead the [hypergeometric distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution).

As an example, the probability of three phones defective, sampling without replacement, is  $${3 \choose 3} \times \frac{5}{20} \times \frac{4}{19} \times \frac{3}{18} \approx 0.00877$$ and the others

$$\mathbb P(X=k)=\frac{{{5\choose k}}{{15\choose 3-k}}}{{20\choose 3}}.$$

Comment: (+1) I fell into the trap as well (shame on me!) :-S